# Associate additional value to a manytomanyfield

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models book and favorite

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Favorite(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='favorited_by')
```

Here a user has its own sets of favorite books. I want to associate an additional variable to each selected favorite book but how can this be done?

Comment: By specifying a `through` model...

Comment: But your modeling is actually quite strange to begin with, you use a `OneToOne` to a user?

Comment: what is the other way? I'm new to django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `through` model: a model that is used to write many-to-many relations. But your modeling in general is a bit strange. Why do you use a `OneToOneField` to a `User` here? Isn't a `Favorite` a *single* favorite (thus the fact that a *single* user likes a *single* book:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Favorite')

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    additional = models.IntegerField()
```

We thus model it as a three models:

```
+-------+ 1   M +------------+ N    1 +------+
| Book  |-------| Favorite   |--------| User |
+-------+       +------------+        +------+
| title |       | additional |
+-------+       +------------+
```

Now `Favorite` is thus seen as the fact that *a* `User` liked *a* `Book`. Not as one-to-one model instance attached to a `User` that will contain *all* favorites.

For more, [see the documentation on the **`through`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

Comment: I am implementing in a way that user can select multiple favorites

Comment: @Ahmed: well that is here perfectly possible, since every favorite a user has, is a *single* `Favorite` instance for that user. It is rather weird that you use a model called `Favorite` to store *multiple `Favorite`s in. In your implementation, the `Favorite` has not much added value, since your `Favorite` basically acts like a proxy object to a `User`.

Comment: Typically using such *shallow* models with only a `OneToOne` field are not good since (a) they create tables that only add data duplication (which is already an anti-pattern), (b) it will make querying more complex, and (c) and it is less efficient.